# cleaner way of mixing PHP switch case with html

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

i have this php block

```
<?php switch ($_GET['class_id']) { ?>
<?php case 1:    ?>
<img src="<?php print $result['standard_image'] == "" ? "/pre_config/css/images/blue-png2.png" : "/shop_possystems/image/{$result['standard_image']}" ?>" alt="" />
<?php break; ?>
<?php case 2:    ?>
<img src="<?php print $result['business_image'] == "" ? "/pre_config/css/images/blue-png2.png" : "/shop_possystems/image/{$result['business_image']}" ?>" alt="" />
<?php break; ?>
<?php case 3:    ?>
<img src="<?php print $result['premium_image'] == "" ? "/pre_config/css/images/blue-png2.png" : "/shop_possystems/image/{$result['premium_image']}" ?>" alt="" />
<?php break; ?>
<?php default: ?>
<img src="<?php print $result['standard_image'] == "" ? "/pre_config/css/images/blue-png2.png" : "/shop_possystems/image/{$result['standard_image']}" ?>" alt="" />
<?php break; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

but this seems a bit messy..any suggestions

Comment: holy cow that's a <?php /**/?> lot of tags!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why all the cases in the first place? You're just picking what image to use.

```
$images = array(
  1 => 'standard_image',
  2 => 'business_image',
  3 => 'premium_image'
);

$id = $_GET['class_id'];
$image_key = (isset($images[$id])) ? $images[$id] : 'standard_image';

$image = '/pre_config/css/images/blue-png2.png';
if ($result[$image_key] != '')
    $image = $result[$image_key];

echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Logo" />';
```

Added bonus: the purpose of the logic is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

```
switch($_GET['class_id'])
{
    case 1:
        $source = '/images/src1.png';
        $class = 'yourClass';
        $alt = 'yourAlt';
    break;

    case 2:
        $source = '/images/src2.png';
        $class = 'yourClass2';
        $alt = 'yourAlt2';
    break;

    case 3:
        $source = '/images/src3.png';
        $class = 'yourClass3';
        $alt = 'yourAlt3';
    break;

    default:
        $source = '/images/src4.png';
        $class = 'yourClass4';
        $alt = 'yourAlt4';
    break;
}

$image = <<<EOF
<img src="$source" class="$class" alt="$alt" />
EOF;

echo $image;
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree, that code is crazy.

Write all the PHP code in a single `<?php ?>` block. When you have to print something, use the print function or echo construct.

Declare variables that can help you read and understand the code.

For example:

```
<?php

switch ($_GET['class_id']) {
    case 1:
       $imgpath = ($result['standard_image'] == "") ? "/pre_config/css/images/blue-png2.png" : "/shop_possystems/image/{$result['standard_image']}";
       echo '<img src="'.$imgpath.'" alt="" />';
       break;
    case 2:
       // and so on for the other cases...
}

?>
```

Isn't it a bit less messy?

Comment: Less messy should include clean clear logic without duplication imo

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$image = $result['standard_image'];
switch ($_GET['class_id']) { 
    case 2: $image = $result['business_image']; break;
    case 3: $image = $result['premium_image']; break;
}
?>
<img src="<?php print $image == "" ? "/pre_config/css/images/blue-png2.png" : "/shop_possystems/image/{$image}"; ?>" alt="" />
```

You don't need to open and close php tags every line.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$img = '';
switch ($_GET['class_id']) { 
  case 1 : 
    $img = $result['standard_image'];
    break;
  case 2 : 
    $img = $result['business_image'];
    break;
  case 3 : 
    $img = $result['premium_image'];
    break;
  default : 
    $img = $result['standard_image'];
    break;
}
if (!$img) {
  $img = 'blue-png2.png';
}
?>
<img src="<?php print $img; ?>" alt="" />
```

You can remove line breaks as you see fit... I format things consistently as a principle, and you should too ! :)

Comment: +1 This is good but I don't like it relies on PHP duck typing (see `if (!$img)`) which looks smart but in fact is less clear. However, well done

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
    array('/images/src1.png', 'yourClass', 'yourAlt'),
    array('/images/src2.png', 'yourClass2', 'yourAlt2'),
    array('/images/src3.png', 'yourClass3', 'yourAlt3'));


echo '<img src="'.$array[$_GET['class_id']][0].'" class="'.$array[$_GET['class_id']][1].'" alt="'.$array[$_GET['class_id']][2].'" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with actually putting this in a block and use a few predefined variables. A little bit cleaner, at least to me...

```
<?php
$p = "/pre_config/css/images/blue-png2.png";
$s = "/shop_possystems/image/";
switch ($_GET['class_id']) {
    case 1:
        $x = (empty($result['standard_image']) ? $p : "{$s}/{$result['standard_image']}";
        break;
    case 2:
        $x = (empty($result['business_image']) ? $p : "{$s}/{$result['business_image']}";
        break;
    case 3:
        $x = (empty($result['premium_image']) ? $p : "{$s}/{$result['standard_image']}";
        break;
    default:
        $x = (empty($result['standard_image']) ? $p : "{$s}/{$result['standard_image']}";
        break;
} 

echo "<img src=\"{$x}\" alt=\"\" />";
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Yes...

```
<?php
$a = array(0, 0, 'business_image', 'premium_image');
$t = $a[(int)$_GET['class_id']] || "standard_image";
echo "<img src=\"";
echo $result[$t] === "" ? "/pre_config/css/images/blue-png2.png" : "/shop_possystems/image/{$result['standard_image']}";
echo "\" />";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can echo your img tags within the case statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the switch, I'd suggest something like the following.

```
<?php 
    $img_type = '';
    switch ($_GET['class_id']) {
    case 1:   
        $img_type = 'standard_image';
        break;
    case 2:
        $img_type = 'business_image';
        break;
    case 3:
        $img_type = 'premium_image';
        break;
    default:
        $img_type = 'standard_image';
        break;
    }
    $src = $result[$img_type] == "" ? "/pre_config/css/images/blue-png2.png" : "/shop_possystems/image/{$result[$img_type]}";
?>
<img src="<?php print $src ?>" alt="" />
```